# Overcoming odd sed behavior

Tags: bash, sed

I've got an output file that's already gotten the following values in it

```
16.1
144.3
352.5
23.4
129.5
993.9
```

I've also got a source file with the following text in it.

```
#0  abc 2016-08-06 01:12:57 AM  9.1%    779.9M of 1G    156.3M of 1G
#1  abc 2016-08-06 02:33:47 AM  12.1%   339.9M of 1G    126.3M of 1G
```

Using grep, I run a loop over the #0 and #1 lines and store the following in variables on the first iteration.

```
$cpu #stores 9.1
$mem #stores 779.9
$disk #stores 156.3
```

The next time, my grep loop runs over the "#1" line, my 3 variables will update to 12.1, 339.9 and 126.3.

I'm trying to use sed to get the output as follows

```
16.1,9.1
144.3,779.9
352.5,156.3
23.4,12.1
129.5,339.9
993.9,126.3
```

I'm using the following sed code in a loop to do this.

```
sed ""$counter"s/$/,"$cpu"/" "$opFile" | tee "$opFile"
((counter++))
sed ""$counter"s/$/,"$mem"/" "$opFile" | tee "$opFile"
((counter++)
sed ""$counter"s/$/,"$disk"/" "$opFile" | tee "$opFile"
```

The reason why I'm using tee is because without it, I get the output like so when run in a script

```
16.1,9.1
144.3
352.5
23.4
129.5
993.9
16.1
144.3,779.9
352.5
23.4
129.5
993.9
```

and so on.. I hope you see what's happening.

Tee provides me the right answer but only works sometimes but with very odd behaviour. On the command line, sometimes it appends to all 6 lines correctly. Another time, it appended to 5 lines and then just made the opFile empty. And another time, on the first try itself it made the opFile empty. Forget command line, at the end of executing my script, everytime my opFile is blank.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat output.txt
16.1
144.3
352.5
23.4
129.5
993.9

$ cat source.txt
#0  abc 2016-08-06 01:12:57 AM  9.1%    779.9M of 1G    156.3M of 1G
#1  abc 2016-08-06 02:33:47 AM  12.1%   339.9M of 1G    126.3M of 1G

$ paste -d, output.txt <(grep -oP '[0-9.]+(?=%)|[0-9.]+(?=[A-Z]+ of)' source.txt)
16.1,9.1
144.3,779.9
352.5,156.3
23.4,12.1
129.5,339.9
993.9,126.3
```

This alternate solution might work, I don't know what's wrong in your approach...

**Edit:**

```
$ paste -d, output.txt <(grep -oP '[0-9.]+(?=%)|[0-9.]+(?=[A-Z]+ of)' source.txt) > tmp ; mv tmp output.txt
```

This will save output in `tmp` file and then moved to `output.txt`

Comment: Was about to post same answer ++

Comment: That's a really nice answer. And it displays it right too, but how would you suggest I input it in to the file? Paste will just display it on screen.

Comment: @spasic that doesn't give me the old values. It shows me ,9.1 ,779.9 ,156.3 ... all on different lines ofcourse. But the initial values of the file are lost.

Comment: @spasic Brilliant. But could you please explain to me why the single redirection didn't work in the first place? Technically, the right output was being displayed and the same thing was redirected into a new file right?

Comment: from your `initial values lost` comment, I gathered that you were trying to change one of files given as input to paste itself.. as far as I know, you cannot do inplace edit with paste.. so I saved the output to a `tmp` file and later moved back to file you needed to change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122120/discussion-between-izy-and-sp-asic).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't completely followed what you're trying to do but you shouldn't be reading from and writing to the same file - this is likely to be where your problem lies.

When you specify the output file to `tee`, it will be opened for writing and truncated. If `sed` gets a chance to read the file before this happens, then things will appear to be working. However, this won't always be the case.

Chances are that your overall process can be simplified but using a temporary file should at least fix the problem.

For example:

```
sed ""$counter"s/$/,"$disk"/" "$opfile" | tee "${opfile}_tmp" && mv "${opfile}_tmp" "$opfile"
```